# Create using dbms_random.value with a specifying scale

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

How can i create random values (between 68 and 69) with specifying scale

for example i want USD to store a value (69.42) but if i will dbms_random.value (68.42,69.99).

He will give more than 2 scale (69.8390172988896) if im using trunc he gives without scale at all.

Im using next code

```
CREATE TABLE T_NEW_TEST
(
USD NUMBER NULL,
EURO NUMBER NULL,
DATEOF DATE NULL
)

INSERT INTO T_NEW_TEST
select TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(68.22,69.99),(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(72.2,74.4)),date '2017-01-01' + (level-1)
from dual
connect by level <= 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to truncate after two digits after the decimal point.

Use `TRUNC(COL, 2)` for that:

```
select TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(68.22,69.99),2),date '2017-01-01' + (level-1)
from dual
connect by level <= 100
```